# Problems with pausing a custom Thread on android

Tags: android, multithreading, surfaceview

hyI'm making a game using a custom class that extends from `SurfaceView` and a custom `Thread` as a loop. I had a problem when the home or return button was pressed. I searched and searched and I found this code that seems it works:

```
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    if (myThread.state==GameThread.PAUSED) {
        myThread = new GameThread(this, getHolder());
    }
    myThread.start();
}
```

Of course i added the variables in the class, but it sometimes works and sometimes not, when it does not work it returns me an error in the first draw statement on the onDraw method of the surface, i don't know why is happening this...

Comment: Check this http://https417.blogspot.com/2012/08/threading-surfaceview-in-android.html

Comment: @eee Thank you very much!!, that solved my problem!! :)

Answer (score 0):

A discussion of the interaction between SurfaceView and the Activity lifecycle can be found [here](https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/architecture.html#activity).  There are some odd corner cases and it's easy to get it wrong.

Various correct examples can be found in [Grafika](https://github.com/google/grafika) (but don't look at [this one](https://github.com/google/grafika/issues/24)... as I said, it's easy to get it wrong).